# Tangent space of a sphere is locally homeomorphic to to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

> Tangent space of $S^n$ is locally homeomorphic to to
> $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

The tangent space is given by $$TS^n=\{(x,v)\in S^n\times R^{n+1} : v\perp x\}\subset S^n\times R^{n+1}$$

I didn't know where to start, so I tried researching. I found the "Whitney embedding theorem" that says:

The theorem states that every n-dimensional differentiable manifold has an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Is there a way of showing this without using this theorem?

Comment: Try to write a local chart around a point (x,v).

Comment: $TS^n$ is usually denoted as *tangent bundle*. Tangent spaces are associated to single points: For $x \in S^n$ you have $T_pM = \{ v \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid v\perp x\}$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but isn't a tangent plane to $S^2$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$? Is the question really asking that the tangent **bundle**, not tangent space, is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can do this from scratch, without much differential geometry. For simplicity, consider $S^2.$ Since the sphere is rotationally invariant, without loss of generality, take $\vec p=(0,0,1).$ There is an open set $p\in U\subseteq S^2$ small enough so that if $\vec x\in U$ then the $z$ coordinate of $x$ is different from zero. i.e. $U$ does not intersect the equator.

Let $\phi:U\to \phi(U)$ be [stereographic projection](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Eboyang/2220%20s2017/math2220_notes/notes_sec_2.1.pdf). $\ \phi $ is a homeomorphism.

If $\vec x=(x,y,z)\in U$ and $\vec v=(a,b,c)\in \mathbb R^3$ such that $\vec x \perp \vec v,\ $ then $ax+by+cz=0.$

Now, define the map

$\Phi:TU\to \phi(U)\times \mathbb R^2: (\vec x,\vec v)=((x,y,z),(a,b,c))\mapsto (\phi(\vec x), (a,b)).$

$\Phi$ is open, surjective and continuous so all we need to prove is that it is injective:

If $(\phi(\vec x_1),\vec v_1)=(\phi(\vec x_2),\vec v_2)$ then $\vec x_1=\vec x_2$ and $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2.$ But then

$a_1x_1+b_1y_1+c_1z_1=a_2x_2+b_2y_2+c_2z_2\Rightarrow$

$a_1x_1+b_1y_1+c_1z_1=a_1x_1+b_1y_1+c_2z_1\Rightarrow c_1=c_2.$

(In the last step we used the fact that $z_1\neq 0.$)

To finish, simply note that $\phi(U)\cong \mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^4\cong \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2.$